# Spring security + JWT + authenticated and hasRole not working?

Tags: spring-mvc, authentication, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

**My problem is that I can't authenticate users when they login**. 
I think my WebSecurityConfig file has problems, as follows:

```
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

// Web Security

@Autowired
private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
}


// Authentication and Authorization

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable();

    //h2 database console
    http.headers().frameOptions().disable();

    http.exceptionHandling()
            .and().anonymous()
            .and().servletApi()
            .and().headers().cacheControl();
    http.addFilterBefore(
            new JWTLoginFilter("/login", authenticationManager()),
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    http.addFilterBefore(
            new JWTAuthenticationFilter(),
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/**").authenticated()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/login").permitAll();

    http.logout()
            .logoutUrl("/api/logout")
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/api/index")
            .invalidateHttpSession(true);

}
```

}

When I use `hasRole("CUSTOMER")` then reponse with value `message: Access is denied`. I do not know where the problem lies.
Several related files:
**JWTLoginFilter:**

```
public class JWTLoginFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {
public JWTLoginFilter(String url, AuthenticationManager authManager) {
    super(new AntPathRequestMatcher(url));
    setAuthenticationManager(authManager);
}

@Override
public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException, IOException, ServletException {
    User credentials = new User(request.getParameter("username"),  request.getParameter("email"), request.getParameter("password"));
    return getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(
            new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                    credentials.getEmail(),
                    credentials.getPassword(),
                    Collections.emptyList()
            )
    );
}

@Override
protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain, Authentication authResult) throws IOException, ServletException {
    TokenAuthenticationService.addAuthentication(response, authResult.getName());
}
```

}
**JWTAuthenticationFilter:**

```
public class JWTAuthenticationFilter extends GenericFilterBean {
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    Authentication authentication = TokenAuthenticationService.getAuthentication((HttpServletRequest) servletRequest);
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
    filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
}
```

}
**TokenAuthenticationService**

```
public class TokenAuthenticationService {
static final long EXPIRATIONTIME = 864_000_000; // 10 days
static final String SECRET = "ThisIsASecret";
static final String TOKEN_PREFIX = "Bearer";
static final String HEADER_STRING = "Authorization";

public static void addAuthentication(HttpServletResponse res, String username) {
    String JWT = Jwts.builder()
            .setSubject(username)
            .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + EXPIRATIONTIME))
            .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, SECRET)
            .compact();
    res.addHeader(HEADER_STRING, TOKEN_PREFIX+ " " + JWT);
}

public static Authentication getAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String token = request.getHeader(HEADER_STRING);

    if (token != null) {
        // parse the token.
        String user = Jwts.parser()
                .setSigningKey(SECRET)
                .parseClaimsJws(token.replace(TOKEN_PREFIX, ""))
                .getBody()
                .getSubject();

        return user != null ?
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, null, emptyList()) :
                null;
    }
    return null;
}
```

}
Please help me! thank!

Answer (score 0):

First, try to create Bean of `BCryptPasswordEncoder` in your main application class which your app run, the class that your main method in. Only init a `BCryptPasswordEncoder` object in `WebSecurityConfig` class.
Also if you can share a git repo of your code, it would be easier to solve. 
[Here](https://github.com/ugurcemozturk/JWT) is my very basic application that uses JWT with Spring Boot, very familiar with your code. Most probably we both tried to learn from 0Auth tutorials.

Comment: hi man, this is my repo link: https://github.com/homanhluc/spring-boot-restful-gamesaccountshop-server